# store the temporary data in memory array or database

Tags: node.js

Just wonder if I need to store the temporary data in memory array or database(nosql)?

Is there any performance difference?

Somebody said nodejs is very dangerous to cache data in memory, it may lead to memory leak. And it cannot afford big data.

Your comment welcome

Comment: i would just use `redis`

Comment: It would lead to memory leaks only if you are not careful. A memory leak is nothing but holding on to the references of a variable. Closure in javascript makes things even murkier. I would take @AJcodez's suggestion and use redis and set an expiry on each record.

Comment: thanks  I will use redis for prompt programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options as storage media, but you are probably best profiling your specific application and making a determination.  You may find that the overhead of connecting to storage, storing and retrieving data outweighs any improvements in your memory footprint.  You might find the opposite - you will need to profile your application to know.

The NPM package `look` is very useful for this type of thing: https://www.npmjs.org/package/look.